# QGIS, How to label a layer in different font sizes, shrink to fit in polygon or a multiple line label?

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling, font

I am just trying to figure out how to label a polygon layer to fit its size in QGIS. or if its very long title should break in line and scale, i did some research but couldn't find anything helpful is there any expression or code to apply?

[As this Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HYtl.jpg)